# Why Allah choose 12 month

Tags: lunar-calendar

I don't understand why God choose 12 month per year why not 53 10 9

because 12 is a special number we know with the qur'an that 1 month means one lunar cycle and there is exactly 12 lunar cycle EVERY year

I don't understand since our hijri calendar doesn't care about solar year

and also I don't understand why some people claimed that prophet was following a solar year in the early days of Islam

I am not sure if this calendar is the right

can you help me explaining why 12? maybe there is other reason

Comment: You have basically asked three questions: 1. Why has Allah chosen 12 months? 2. Is there an evidence for the prophet having used solar calendar in early days of Islam? 3. is a bit vague: are you wondering whether the lunar or solar calendar is right? Do you need an explanation for the reason for the 12 months?. As to the first question it is hard for us to judge Allah's choice unless He gave us some hints. For the second question I'd doubt this and would ask for evidences for such a claim. And further it might be more helpful if you explained or confirmed my contemplation about your post.

Comment: Be aware that verse (9:36) which was quoted in the answer below certainly could be explained with more details. As for the calendars of the Arabs they may have used a lunisolar calendar (not a solar calendar). Either because they have copied the idea from the Jews or because they found it useful too.

Answer (score 1):

It is simply how Allah made things. He decided the number of months is 12. Allah says:

> Indeed, the number of months with Allah is twelve [lunar] months in the register of Allah [from] the day He created the heavens and the earth; of these, four are sacred. That is the correct religion, so do not wrong yourselves during them. And fight against the disbelievers collectively as they fight against you collectively. And know that Allah is with the righteous [who fear Him]. (9:36)

Asking why is no different to asking why there are 7 skies rather than 10 or why is the Kaabah at Makkah rather than another city. It's simply God's choice.

A reason could be that the 12 lunar months are convenient because they line up with the solar year even if off by a few days in addition to the advantage of easy measurement using the moon. This may have helped people in the past to keep track of the seasons. They would know that summer starts only a few days later than it started last year.

However, then you could ask why is the solar year 365 days long rather than 300 days long. It's simply God's decision when He created the universe. There is no need to have a much deeper reason.

In addition, perhaps you do not realize this but the solar year gets its 12 months from the lunar year not vice versa. Originally, all humans followed the lunar year. Then, some people modified it and made a new calendar to follow the solar year exactly. Thus, the 12 months are a remnant from the originally followed lunar year.

Answer (score 0):

Because every thing is calculated. Even the words of  Kalima Tayyiba has 24 letters. 12 Allah has for himself and 12 for Prophet Muhammad PBUH.
Months and days depends on the movement of entire universe. It depends upon how long stars or planet takes to complete their circle. Thats why temperature, time duration of day and night is different in each planet. You slightly change the pattern the entire scenario will be changed.  For example if you change the formula of H2O on earth then life become impossible. Every thing is perfectly calculated as mentioned in Quran:
It is He who has created seven heavens, one above the other. You can see no flaw in the creation of the Beneficent God. Look again. Can you see faults? (Surah Mulk Ayat No. 3)